# Pycharm cant find pyside libs installed by brew

Tags: pycharm, homebrew, pyside

I have python@3.10 and pyside2 installed using brew.

I create virtual env:

1. create env `python3.10 -m venv env`
2. activate it with `source env/bin/activate`
3. check python version `python -version` and i get python3.10 .
4. open python console `python`
5. import pyside2 lib -> `from PySide2.QtCore import QObject`
6. no error message, it can successfully import.
7. Then i create python file `main.py` in PyCharm. Pycharm uses this *env*.
8. But it **complains cant find** PySide libs `from PySide2.QtCore import QObject`

Note: I cant install pyside2 using pip, it must be installed by brew.

many thanks.